# How to Make Eclipse Java Set Project Dependency to Solution Project Instead of Reference JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, reference

I have a java Eclipse solution. In this solution, there are 2 projects:

1 library project and 1 test project

The Problem: The exact library project classes also exist in a referenced jar file and test project tend to use the classes in the jar file instead of the library project in the same solution.

My pseduo-solution was to remove the library classes in the referenced jar file and the test project successuly used the library project directly. However, I suspect there may be a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps will fix this issue:

> 1. Project's context menu
> 2. Configure
> 3. "Order & Export"
> 4. Move things up-and-down as per your requirement.

Comment: @AngelinaJolly The problem is the first sentence of the answer: `Have you tried setting an order to build path entries?`In Stackoverflow we don't count questions as answers  ;)

Comment: @AndréSchild: Thanks for this: `The problem is the first sentence of the answer: Have you tried setting an order to build path entries?In Stackoverflow we don't count questions as answers ;)`. Edited the answer accordingly. Hope it looks better now :)